# how can i use two sequence simultaenously in lstm

Tags: keras, sequence, lstm

I want to train a lstm supervised learning model. and i have two useful seq, one is the action, the other is the gap time between action. and i want to use both of them.

my code is below, it can run, but i don't think it's make sense.
in_action and in_time are two seq, which length is 64. and i embeded each element to 128d.
then i concatenate them and put into LSTM,

```py
in_action = Input(batch_shape=(None,64), dtype='int32', name='in_action')
in_time = Input(batch_shape=(None,64), dtype='int32', name='in_time')
embedded_sequence_act = Embedding(501, 128)(in_action)
embedded_sequence_time = Embedding(501, 128)(in_time)
concate_embedding = Concatenate(axis=-1)([embedded_sequence_act, embedded_sequence_time])

n_features=2
model = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(64, n_features))(concate_embedding)
model = LSTM(32, return_sequences=True)(model)
model = LSTM(16)(model)

output = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", name='prediction')(model)
model = Model(inputs=[in_action, in_time], outputs=output)
model.compile(
             loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
                metrics=['acc'])
```

and i change n_features to any number (say 3,7,20),it can run...I don't understand why
though it can run, plz help me figure out how show i edit my code, so the code makes sense

Comment: You don't need the `input_shape` argument here. You only need it when using the `Sequential` model, and there only the very first layer needs it. I'm not sure why it still works and what happens here... in the best case it is simply ignored. In the worst case the actual input shape `(64, 2*128)` gets truncated to `(64, n_features)` which would explain poor performance. Either way, you should remove `input_shape`. Besides that, concatenating vectors in order to feed both into one LSTM *does* make sense to me. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: As @sebrockm, i also think that concatenating is a good option. It is frequently used to provide different inputs to RNNs.

Comment: @sebrockm Thank you!  If i concatenate them like my code, the seq would like [act_seq, time_seq]. In this way,  the model will receive act_seq(say 128d) first, then time_seq. It may add some information to the model, but does it give much help?

Comment: @MasterJiQ not sure if I understand you... if you concatenate along the last axis ( as you do with `axis=-1`), you will turn your two sequences of shape `(64, 128)` into one sequence of shape `(64, 256)`, which does make sense. If, however, you concatenate along the second last axis (the time axis `axis=-2`) you would effectively double your sequence length resulting in `(128, 128)` which makes no sense (at least not in your scenario).

Comment: @sebrockm got it!